# Sending and receiving frames over the same websocket connection without blocking

Tags: python, websocket, python-3.6, python-asyncio

Sorry for the long post but I've been poking at this for over a week so I've tried a lot of different stuff. I know Python well enough but I don't have any experience with asyncio or non-blocking functions in Python.

I'm writing an API library/module/package/whatever for a web service that requires a websocket connection. There are many incoming messages to act on, and some control-related (web app level, not websocket control messages) that I need to send on occasion. I can easily receive messages over the connection and act on them. I can send messages, but only in response to received messages because the receive loop is always blocking waiting for messages. I don't want to wait for an incoming messages to process an outgoing one so the script doesn't have to hang on input until a new messages is received. In my struggles to get two-way communication working as desired I discovered I need to use something like Twisted, Tornado, or asyncio but so far every implementation I've tried has failed. Note that the sending has to happen over the same connection. Opening a short-lived connection outside of the receive loop will not work. Here's what I've done so far:

---

The first iteration of the websocket code was using the [websocket-client](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/) package. It was very close to the example from the docs:

```
import websocket
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    # Send message frames to respective functions
    # for sorting, objectification, and processing

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        # Send initial frames required for server to send the desired frames
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(buildWebsocketURL()),
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

This blocks any further execution outside of the loop. I tried learning up on the _thread module but I couldn't find any indication that I could "communicate" with the websocket thread from outside. I tried setting up a pub/sub listener function that would forward data to `ws.send()` from another sender function but it didn't work. No errors or anything, just no indication of any sent messages.

---

Next I tried the [Websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) module. This one seems to be built from the ground up to utilize asyncio. Again, I got a client build that would send initial messages and act on received messages but the progress stopped there:

```
async def wsconnection():
        async with websockets.connect(getWebsocketURL()) as websocket:
            while True:
                message = await websocket.recv()
                if message == '{"type":"broadcaster.ready"}':
                    subscriptions = getSubscriptions()  # Get subscriptions from ident data
                    logging.info('Sending bookmarks to server as subscription keys')
                    subscriptionupdate = '{{"type": "subscribe","subscription_keys": ["{0}"],"subscription_scope": "update"}}'.format(
                        '","'.join(subscriptions))
                    subscriptioncontent = '{{"subscription_keys": ["{0}"],"subscription_scope": "content","type": "subscribe"}}'.format(
                        '","'.join(subscriptions))
                    logging.debug(subscriptioncontent)
                    await websocket.send(subscriptionupdate)
                    await websocket.send(subscriptioncontent)
                    await websocket.send(
                        '{"type":"message_lobby.read","lobby_id":"1","message_id:"16256829"}')
                sortframe(message) 

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(wsconnection())
```

I tried the aforementioned pub/sub listener applied here to no avail. Upon reading the docs for this module more thoroughly I tried getting the websocket protocol object (that contains the send() and recv() methods) outside of the loop then creating two coroutines(?), one listening for incoming messages and one listening for and sending outgoing messages. So far I've been completely unable to get the websocket protocol object without running the `async with websockets.connect(getWebsocketURL()) as websocket:` line within the scope of the wsconnection() function. I tried using `websocket = websockets.client.connect()` which according to the [docs](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#module-websockets.client) I thought would set the protocol object I need but it doesn't. All of the examples I can find don't seem to reveal any apparent way to structure the websockets sender and receiver in the way I require without extensive knowledge of asyncio.

---

I also  poked around with [autobahn](https://autobahn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with similar code structures as above using both asyncio and Twisted but I came up with all the same problems as above.

So far the closest I've gotten was with the Websockets package above. The docs have an [example snippet](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#both) for a send/recv connection but I can't really read what's going on there as it's all very specific to asyncio. I'm really having trouble wrapping my head around asyncio in general and I think a big problem is it seems to have very rapidly evolved recently so there is a ton of very version-specific information floating around that conflicts. Not good for learning, unfortunately. ~~~~This is what I tried using that example and it connects, receives initial messages, then the connection is lost/closed:

```
async def producer(message):
    print('Sending message')

async def consumer_handler(websocket, path):
    while True:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        await print(message)
        await pub.sendMessage('sender', message)

async def producer_handler(websocket, path):
    while True:
        message = await producer()
        await websocket.send(message)

async def wsconnect():
        async with websockets.connect(getWebsocketURL()) as websocket:
            path = "443"
            async def handler(websocket, path):
                consumer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(
                    consumer_handler(websocket, path))
                producer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(
                    producer_handler(websocket, path))
                done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
                    [consumer_task, producer_task],
                    return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,
                )
                for task in pending:
                    task.cancel()

pub.subscribe(producer, 'sender')

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(wsconnect())
```

So how do I structure this code to get sending and receiving over the same websocket connection? I also have various API calls to make in the same script while the websocket connection is open which further complicates things.

I'm using Python 3.6.6 and this script is intended to be imported as a module into other scripts so the websocket functionality will need to be wrapped up in a function or class for external calls.

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if you could concentrate on one approach. For example, since you're posting under `python-asyncio`, the second one using asyncio websockets.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the exact same situation as u. I know that this is a very inelegant solution
because it still isn't full-duplex but i can't seem to find any example on the internet or stackoverflow involving asyncio and the websockets module which i used.

I don't think i completely understand your websockets example (is that server-side or client-side code?) but i'm going to explain my situation and "solution" and maybe that would be usable for you too.

So i have a server main function that has a websocket listening for messages in a loop with recv(). When i send "start" it will start a function that will send data every second to the javascript client in the browser. But while the function is sending data i sometimes want to pause or stop the stream of data from my client be sending a stop message. The problem is that when i use recv() while the data sending has already begun the server stops sending data and only waits for a message. I tried threads,multiprocessing and some other stuff but eventually i came to the hopefully temporarily solution of sending a "pong" message to the server immediately after the client receives a piece of data so that the server continues sending data at the next loop iteration or stop sending data if the "pong" message is "stop" instead for example but yeah this is not real duplex just fast half-duplex...

code on my python "server"

```
 async def start_server(self,websocket,webserver_path):
    self.websocket = websocket
    self.webserver_path = webserver_path
    while True:
        command = await self.websocket.recv()
        print("received command")
        if command == "start":
            await self.analyze()
        asyncio.sleep(1)
```

in my analyze function:

```
        for i,row in enumerate(data)
            await self.websocket.send(json.dumps(row))
            msg = await self.websocket.recv()
            if msg == "stop":
                self.stopFlag = True
                return
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

main

```
start_server = websockets.serve(t.start_server, "127.0.0.1", 5678)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

code on the javascript client

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5678/");
        ws.onmessage = function (event) {
            var datapoint = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(counter);
            counter++;
            data.push(datapoint);
            if (data.length > 40){
                var element = data.shift();
                render(data);
            }
            ws.send("pong");//sending dummy message to let server continue
        };
```

I know it is not THE solution and i hope somebody else provides a better one but since i have the same or very similar problem and there are no other answers i decided to post and i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, my work around for this that works so well I forgot I was doing it is to spawn a separate thread, I use `threading`, that encapsulates everything else that you want to continue doing while the websocket connection is running. Then do the websockets run forever stuff as the last lines of the main function where it will still be "blocking" but there is nothing being blocked.

```
...

thread = threading.Thread(target=other_stuff)
thread.start()

...

websocket_server = websockets.serve(websocket_handler, HOST_IP, HOST_PORT)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websocket_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Basically the `other_stuff` function acts as your real "main" function while websockets gets to eat its cake all alone. I actually run a normal HTTP server in the separate thread so this one script handles all HTTP requests and bi-directional websocket messages at the same time. So far I haven't had any sort of blocking issues.

My use case involves relatively low traffic overall, so I'm not sure how this all scales for higher volume servers.