# Python and WebSockets - how to send from server to client without blocking?

Tags: python, websocket

Can anybody explain, or better yet provide a working example, of how to write a Python client and server where the server can initiate a send via WebSocket at any arbitrary time based on processing logic, and the client can receive at any time?  Both have to be freed up to perform other processing activities as their majority purpose.

I've Googled extensively for this, including looking into [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/), which seems to be the classic Python option and [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), and [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) which seem to be the newer way.  In either case, every working example I can find is based on the client initiating the communication.  Some cover sending from server to client as an echo where the client's logic initiates the series of communication, but I need to get an example working where the server initiates the communication.

Many `Tornado` examples are timeout based which won't work in my case.  The `websockets` and `asyncio` examples all are either client to server and/or have a line like `somethingOrOther.run()` which blocks execution on the client or server or both. Also, many examples have one of either the client or the server written in Python but the other written in something else like JavaScript (I need both in Python).

I don't need the connection to be full-duplex, that is to say, the client never has to send to the server on the same socket, except perhaps for sending back an acknowledgment.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652755/sending-and-receiving-frames-over-the-same-websocket-connection-without-blocking) seems to be similar, however, the poster's code is not complete, there is no accepted answer, and the one answer provided (not accepted) does not contain complete code, and the client is in JavaScript (I need both in Python).

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do using regular sockets:

server:

```
# server.py

import socket
import time
import random

# module-level variables
HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=65439

ACK_TEXT = 'ack_text'


def main():

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    sock.listen()
    conn, addr = sock.accept()

    while True:
        # In an actual program some significant processing/logic would happen here that would take time
        # and also produce a certain result, depending on which we may or may not need to send a message.
        # To simulate this, we'll pause for a short and random amount of time, then get a random integer.
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 1.0))
        myRandInt = random.randint(0, 10)

        # if the ranom integer is even, send a message
        if myRandInt % 2 == 0:
            message = str(myRandInt)
            print('sending message: ' + message)
            sendTextViaSocket(conn, message)
        # end if
    # end while

# end function

def sendTextViaSocket(conn, message):

    # encode the message
    encodedMessage = bytes(message, 'utf-8')
    # send the encoded message
    conn.sendall(encodedMessage)

    # receive the encoded acknowledgement
    encodedAck = conn.recv(1024)
    # decode the acknowledgement
    ack = encodedAck.decode('utf-8')
    # check the received acknowledgement is correct, if not log an error
    if ack == ACK_TEXT:
        pass
    else:
        print('error: acknowledgement was received as ' + str(ack))
    # end if
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

client:

```
# client

import socket
import select
import time
import random

# module-level variables
HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=65439

ACK_TEXT = 'ack_text'


def main():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # if the client is started 1st connect will crash, so continually try to connect
    # in a try-catch until the server is available
    connectionSuccessful = False
    while not connectionSuccessful:
        try:
            sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
            connectionSuccessful = True
        except:
            pass
        # end try
    # end while

    socks = [ sock ]

    # endlessly receive messages
    while True:

        readySocks, _, _ = select.select(socks, [], [], 0)

        for readySock in readySocks:
            message = receiveTextViaSocket(readySock)
            print('received message = ' + str(message))
        # end for

        # In an actual program client would have other significant tasks to do
        # To simulate this we'll pause for a short but random amount of time
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 1.0))
    # end while

# end function

def receiveTextViaSocket(sock):
    # receive the encoded message
    encodedMessage = sock.recv(1024)
    # decode the message
    message = encodedMessage.decode('utf-8')

    # now send the acknowledgement
    # encode the acknowledgement
    encodedAck = bytes(ACK_TEXT, 'utf-8')
    # send the encoded acknowledgement
    sock.sendall(encodedAck)

    return message
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I do the same thing, but with WebSockets ??

--- Edit ---

After spending most of today on this, this is the best I have done so far:

server:

```
# server.py

import threading
import asyncio
import websockets
import collections
import random
import time

sendMessageQueue = collections.deque()

def main():
    webSocketServer = websockets.serve(sendMessages, 'localhost', 8765)
    myLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    webSockThread = threading.Thread(target=webSockStart, args=(webSocketServer, myLoop,))

    webSockThread.start()

    while True:
        myRandInt = random.randint(1, 10)
        print('appending ' + str(myRandInt))
        sendMessageQueue.append(str(myRandInt))
        print('sendMessageQueue = ' + str(sendMessageQueue))
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 2.0))
    # end while

# end function

def webSockStart(webSocketServer, myLoop):
    myLoop.run_until_complete(webSocketServer)
    myLoop.run_forever()
# end function

async def sendMessages(websocket, path):
    while len(sendMessageQueue) > 0:
        await websocket.send(sendMessageQueue.popleft())
    # end while
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

client:

```
# client.py

import threading
import asyncio
import websockets
import collections
import random
import time

receiveMessageQueue = collections.deque()

def main():
    receiveWebSockThread = threading.Thread(target=receiveWebSockStart)
    receiveWebSockThread.start()

    while True:
        print('doing other stuff')
        time.sleep(1.0)

        while len(receiveMessageQueue) > 0:
            message = receiveMessageQueue.popleft()
            print('message = ' + str(message))
        # end while
    # end while

# end function

def receiveWebSockStart():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(receiveMessages())
    loop.run_forever()
# end function

async def receiveMessages():
    while True:
        uri = 'ws://localhost:8765'
        async with websockets.connect(uri) as webSockConn:
            message = await webSockConn.recv()
            receiveMessageQueue.append(str(message))
            # while True:

            # end while
        # end with
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

server output:

```
$ python3 server.py
appending 3
sendMessageQueue = deque(['3'])
appending 8
sendMessageQueue = deque(['8'])
appending 8
sendMessageQueue = deque(['8', '8'])
appending 6
sendMessageQueue = deque(['8', '8', '6'])
appending 1
sendMessageQueue = deque(['8', '8', '6', '1'])
```

client output:

```
$ python3 client.py 
doing other stuff
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "client.py", line 30, in receiveWebSockStart
    loop.run_until_complete(receiveMessages())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "client.py", line 38, in receiveMessages
    message = await webSockConn.recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 509, in recv
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 812, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: code = 1000 (OK), no reason

message = 3
doing other stuff
doing other stuff
doing other stuff
doing other stuff
```

The server seems to be working as intended, however the client is disconnecting after receiving one message and I'm not sure why or how to resolve it.  I'm not sure if threads are even the correct approach, or if I should be using `run_in_executor` from `concurrent.futures`, but I couldn't get that to work at all.  Anybody with specific knowledge on this topic please help.

--- Edit2 ---

Well, at least I found an answer that works (tested with Python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04), but I'm really not happy with it:

server:

```
# server.py

import threading
import asyncio
import websockets
import collections
import random
import time

sendMessageQueue = collections.deque()

def main():
    # start the WebSocket sending on a separate thread so it doesn't block main
    webSockSendThread = threading.Thread(target=sendWebSockStart)
    webSockSendThread.start()

    while True:
        # make up a random integer and append it to the send queue
        myRandInt = random.randint(1, 10)
        print('appending ' + str(myRandInt))
        sendMessageQueue.append(str(myRandInt))

        # an actual program would have many other activities to do here, use a random sleep to simulate this
        print('doing other stuff')
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 2.0))
    # end while

# end function

def sendWebSockStart():
    # since we're in a separate thread now, call new_event_loop() (rather than the usual get_event_loop())
    # and set the returned loop as the current loop
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    # instantiate the WebSocket server, note this also connects it to the sendMessages function
    webSocketServer = websockets.serve(sendMessages, 'localhost', 8765)
    # run the webSocketServer forever, which runs the sendMessages function forever
    loop.run_until_complete(webSocketServer)
    loop.run_forever()      # note execution of this separate thread stays on this line forever
# end function

async def sendMessages(websocket, path):
    while True:
        while len(sendMessageQueue) > 0:
            await websocket.send(sendMessageQueue.popleft())
        # end while
    # end while
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

client:

```
# client.py

import threading
import asyncio
import websockets
import collections
import random
import time

receiveMessageQueue = collections.deque()

def main():
    # start the WebSocket receiving on a separate thread so it doesn't block main
    receiveWebSockThread = threading.Thread(target=receiveWebSockStart)
    receiveWebSockThread.start()

    while True:
        # dequeue and print out all the messages in the receive queue currently
        while len(receiveMessageQueue) > 0:
            message = receiveMessageQueue.popleft()
            print('message = ' + str(message))
        # end while

        # an actual program would have many other activities to do here, use a sleep to simulate this
        print('doing other stuff')
        time.sleep(1.0)
    # end while

# end function

def receiveWebSockStart():
    # since we're in a separate thread now, call new_event_loop() rather than the usual get_event_loop()
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    # run receiveMessages() forever
    loop.run_until_complete(receiveMessages())
    loop.run_forever()      # note execution of this separate thread stays on this line forever
# end function

async def receiveMessages():
    # set up the connection
    uri = 'ws://localhost:8765'
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as webSockConn:
        # endlessly receive messages and append to the queue when received
        while True:
            message = await webSockConn.recv()
            receiveMessageQueue.append(str(message))
        # end while
    # end with
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

server output:

```
$ python3 server.py 
appending 10
doing other stuff
appending 6
doing other stuff
appending 2
doing other stuff
appending 8
doing other stuff
appending 2
doing other stuff
appending 3
doing other stuff
appending 9
doing other stuff
```

client output:

```
$ python3 client.py 
doing other stuff
message = 10
message = 6
doing other stuff
doing other stuff
message = 2
doing other stuff
doing other stuff
message = 8
doing other stuff
doing other stuff
message = 2
doing other stuff
doing other stuff
message = 3
doing other stuff
message = 9
doing other stuff
```

I'm using `threading` as an intermediary between `main` and the `asyncio` `websockets` function.  Can anybody explain or better yet provide a working example of how to re-work this to use `run_in_executor` to eliminate the intermediary thread ??

Comment: Anybody out there?  I'm surprised this is not a more common concern . . .